# Checks for invalid user input java

Tags: java, input

```
if (standOrTerraceTickets != 1 && standOrTerraceTickets != 2) {
    System.out.print("Invalid input. Please enter 1 for stand tickets or 2 for terrace tickets. ");
}
if (standOrTerraceTickets == 1 || standOrTerraceTickets == 2) {
    System.out.print("Now, how many adult tickets do you require? ");
}
int adultTickets = aScanner.nextInt();
System.out.print("How many children's tickets do you require? ");
```

So on this piece above when the user initially inputs 3 (and not 1 or 2) the error message `invalid input` prints. When they enter 1 it skips this print

`Now, how many adult tickets do you require?`

and moves straight onto children's tickets.

Why is that?

Comment: You have to call it in a loop until the user enters the correct input.

Comment: You need to scan for the response after printing "Invalid input..."

Comment: Yes you need a loop and I think the latter part should go inside the second `if` block. The second if block can be the `else` block of the if which would increase performance.

Comment: As you are a new user here, let me tell you, you should accept an answer here if you get a solution to your question. It helps others to know what worked for you. To accept an answer you should just click on the Right Tick sign on the left side of answer you want to select.

Answer (score 2):

You need to improve your conditions.

What you need here is `nested if-else`. As of now your last statement `System.out.print("How many children's tickets do you require? ");` will always run, for any input.

```
int adultTickets = 0;
if (standOrTerraceTickets != 1 && standOrTerraceTickets != 2) {
    System.out.print("Invalid input. Please enter 1 for stand tickets or 2 for terrace tickets. ");
}
else if (standOrTerraceTickets == 1 || standOrTerraceTickets == 2) {
    System.out.print("Now, how many adult tickets do you require? ");
    adultTickets = aScanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("How many children's tickets do you require? ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use following switch case construct.

```
switch(standOrTerraceTickets) 
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        System.out.print("Now, how many adult tickets do you require? ");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.print("Invalid input. Please enter 1 for stand tickets or 2 for terrace tickets. ");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If input is 3 the error message appears - whilst the input is incorrect the error message should display. If the input is 1 or 2 (both valid inputs) no error message appears and the adult ticket number is input. Then the prompt for child tickets is displayed.

```
while (standOrTerraceTickets != 1 && standOrTerraceTickets != 2)
{
   System.out.print("Invalid input. Please enter 1 for stand tickets or 2 for terrace tickets. ");
   standOrTerraceTickets = aScanner.nextInt();
}
System.out.print("Now, how many adult tickets do you require? ");
int adultTickets = aScanner.nextInt();
System.out.print("How many children's tickets do you require? ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply because input is 3 and the if sentence is executed only if `standOrTerraceTickets == 1 || standOrTerraceTickets == 2`